# case insensitive explicit ordering guava

Tags: java, guava

Below code returns output 'ladies' correctly because case sensitive.

```
import com.google.common.collect.SortedSetMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.TreeMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;

private static final Ordering<String> PRODUCT_ORDER = Ordering
            .explicit("men","ladies")
            .reverse();


private void testGuavaOrdering() {
        SortedSetMultimap<Integer, String> onlineAreaPriorityCountMap = TreeMultimap
                .create(Collections.reverseOrder(), PRODUCT_ORDER);
        onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.put(1, "men");
        onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.put(1, "men");
        onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.put(1, "ladies");
        onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.put(1, "ladies");
        System.out.println(onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.values().iterator().next());
    }
```

But, below code not working and throws exception if i change from men to Men.

```
private static final Ordering<String> PRODUCT_ORDER = Ordering
            .explicit("Men","Ladies")
            .reverse()


private void testGuavaOrdering() {
        SortedSetMultimap<Integer, String> onlineAreaPriorityCountMap = TreeMultimap
                .create(Collections.reverseOrder(), PRODUCT_ORDER);
        onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.put(1, "men");
        onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.put(1, "men");
        onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.put(1, "ladies");
        onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.put(1, "ladies");
        System.out.println(onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.values().iterator().next());
    }
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.collect.Ordering$IncomparableValueException: Cannot compare value: men
    at com.google.common.collect.ExplicitOrdering.rank(ExplicitOrdering.java:46)
    at com.google.common.collect.ExplicitOrdering.compare(ExplicitOrdering.java:40)
    at com.google.common.collect.ReverseOrdering.compare(ReverseOrdering.java:38)
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1295)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap.put(AbstractMapBasedMultimap.java:195)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractSetMultimap.put(AbstractSetMultimap.java:121)
    at com.google.common.collect.TreeMultimap.put(TreeMultimap.java:78)
    at TestMap.testGuavaOrdering(TestMap.java:38)
    at TestMap.main(TestMap.java:32)
```

How to do case insensitive compare in guava?

Comment: Shouldn't the case variation be in the target map? Or is the explicit ordering outside of your control?

Comment: To everyone who keeps flagging as duplicate, please read the question carefully. If you still think another answer is relevant, test it to confirm.

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate question as i have custom explicit order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make the `Ordering` itself case-insensitive, but if you can make its values all lowercase, you can wrap it in a `Comparator` that transforms input to lowercase before ranking:

```
private static final Ordering<String> PRODUCT_ORDER = Ordering
        .explicit("men","ladies")
        .reverse();


private static void testGuavaOrdering() {
    SortedSetMultimap<Integer, String> onlineAreaPriorityCountMap = TreeMultimap
            .create(Collections.reverseOrder(),
                    Comparator.comparing(String::toLowerCase, PRODUCT_ORDER));
    onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.put(1, "Men");
    onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.put(1, "men");
    onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.put(1, "Ladies");
    onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.put(1, "ladies");
    System.out.println(onlineAreaPriorityCountMap.values().iterator().next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you have at least 3 options (in descending viability, i.e. I'd suggest using the first if possible):

1. Provide a custom `Comparator` to the `TreeMultimap`, one that handles case as you want it to (see shmosel's answer for an implementation).
2. Provide a wrapper/factory for `ExplicitOrdering` that brings all values to the same case upon creation and in the `rank()` method. You could use that if you don't have influence on the values that are passed for the implicit ordering. However, you could also use a combination of option 1 for the comparisons (bringing the strings to lower case before they are fed to `ExplicitOrdering`) and feeding the constructor with an array of pre-transformed input strings.
3. Provide a wrapper around the strings that implements `equals()` (and `hashcode()`) in a case-insensitive way. Use those for your ordering as well as map keys.

Comment: Regarding point 3 you will need also to override `compareTo()`

Comment: @sargue no, since `ExplicitOrdering` won't call `compareTo()` on the elements but do a rank lookup in a map. Besides that, the elements aren't required to implement `Comparable` so there's no guarantee that there even is a `compareTo()` to override.

Comment: I don't understand your second solution. Mind posting an example?

Comment: @shmosel this seems to be a bit confusing as options 1 and 2 are quite similar. Basically option 2 would be like your proposed solution but with the addition that - if you don't have control over the ordering given or don't want to - you'd bring the values passed as explicit ordering to lower case in an overridden constructor or factory method.

Comment: @Thomas I don't think that's possible. Guava is very restrictive with visibility of its internal classes/methods.

Comment: @shmosel you're right, having a second look at `ExplicitOrdering` shows that the class is final, though `Ordering` isn't and thus a wrapper/factory should still be possible. I'll update the suggestion though to include the factory possibility as well.

Comment: The point is you'd have to rewrite the explicit comparator from scratch, so we're not using Guava. If it specifically needs to be an `Ordering`, you can call `Ordering.from(Comparator)`, but I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: I converted my list to lower values and compared with ordering

Comment: Thanks for all your response.

Comment: @shmosel in the OP's case he doesn't explicitly need an `Ordering` hence writing a custom comparator or a wrapper would be a viable though not preferred option. I just mentioned it for him to have a list choose from, depending on other (not yet mentioned) requirements/parameters.